# How to solve that error? ...is not yet fully supported in Kotlin reflection

Tags: kotlin

I learn how to use ".run" in Kotlin and get this error:

Introspecting local functions, lambdas, anonymous functions and local variables is not yet fully supported in Kotlin reflection

My code:

````
    fun message(isLong: Boolean):String
            { if (isLong){ return "Too long!" }
            else{ return "Normal" }
    }

        val usr = "kivinus"
        val res = usr.run{::nameIsLong}.run{::message}
        println(res)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `run` extension function incorrectly.

You're code can be corrected in two way:

```kotlin
val res = usr.run(::nameIsLong).run(::message)
```

or

```kotlin
val res = usr.run { nameIsLong(this) }.run { message(this) }
```